# Can services in the service layer communicate with each other?

Tags: architecture, c#-4.0

I have a Service Layer, in which my PredictionService needs to know if a certain Race exists. The RaceService has a method `DoesRaceExist()`, but I am not sure if the services can communicate.

That also leads me to some other problems. Lets say I have an `Predictions.aspx` page. I implement with MVP, and so when the page is first requested, the `Initialize()` method in the presenter runs. The `Predictions.aspx` needs multiple pieces of information, from predictions and from races, maybe even more. Should I ask all these pieces from their appropriate services, or should I query the database just one time and get all the information that I need in one go? The problem is then which Service to pick, and then that the service probably does more than just relaying what it is intended for.

What is the best way to go about?

Answer (score 8):

If serviceA needs to get data or run a action on serviceB, it is fine to call serviceB from serviceA.

You might, however, find yourself in a situation where services call each other all over the place - if that happens, consider using a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that orchestrates the different services (so they don't call each other directly).

Comment: Right. I took a hard look at my Prediction presenter and saw that I was using 2 other different kinds of service {Driver, Race} next to my Prediction service. I thought about what you said and thought that indeed it would be a good idea to have a facade/macro service.